# Regex Matches group c#

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

Regex Matches group letter

I'm using regex like:

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(input, @"\$.");
```

input:

```
$08$19$eABCDEF$fw123578$iA12356-78$j$k$xabc123
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Zri.png)
I want to:

```
Code: $0 - Data: 8
Code: $1 - Data: 9
Code: $e - Data: ABCDEF
Code: $f - Data: w123578
Code: $i - Data: A12356-78
Code: $j - Data: 
Code: $k - Data: 
Code: $x - Data: abc123
```

please help me.

Comment: Sounds like you want `Matches(input, @"(\$.)(.*?)(?=\$|$)")`

Comment: You could write it like this, with a single capture group `\$.([^$]+)` https://regex101.com/r/sMG4gR/1

Comment: `var dict = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\$[^$])([^$]*)").Cast<Match>().ToDictionary(x => x.Groups[1].Value, x => x.Groups[2].Value);`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `\$.` where the `.` can match any character except a newline ( so it can also match spaces)

To get the data that you want, you can use a single capture group, excluding to match a dollar sign:

```
(\$.)([^$]+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FKWlrP/1) and a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/V9q9TT)

If you don't want to match spaces, you can use `\S` instead of `.` to match a non whitespace character:

```
(\$\S)([^$]+)
```

Example

```
string pattern = @"(\$.)([^$]*)";
string s = @"$08$19$eABCDEF$fw123578$iA12356-78$j$k$xabc123";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Code: {0} - Data: {1}", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Output

```
Code: $0 - Data: 8
Code: $1 - Data: 9
Code: $e - Data: ABCDEF
Code: $f - Data: w123578
Code: $i - Data: A12356-78
Code: $j - Data: 
Code: $k - Data: 
Code: $x - Data: abc123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the regex pattern to capture the specific groups you want. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
string input = "$08$19$eABCDEF$fw123578$iA12356-78$j$k$xabc123";
        
MatchCollection matchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, @"\$([a-zA-Z\d])([^$]*)");
foreach (Match match in matchCollection)
{
    if (match.Success)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Code: ${m.Groups[1].Value} - Data: {m.Groups[2].Value}");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Code: $0 - Data: 8
Code: $1 - Data: 9
Code: $e - Data: ABCDEF
Code: $f - Data: w123578
Code: $i - Data: A12356-78
Code: $j - Data: 
Code: $k - Data: 
Code: $x - Data: abc123
```

[See this **db<>fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q8ZBa4).